# how to update a table in SQL Server using Integration Services?

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I'm trying to update a table in SQL Server with Integration Services, but I don't know how to do that

All I have is the set of data that need to be updated (with the same structure of the table that should be updated)

Is there some object to do this??

---

I am using OLE DB command with a store procedure to solve this problem. The store procedure have de update sentence and is calling for OLE DB command Object

But, Is there a better solution???

Comment: What version of SSIS are you using? Can you provide more information about your control flow/data flow?

Comment: Have you read any of the SSIS documentation?

Comment: I have been following this [link](http://consultingblogs.emc.com/jamiethomson/archive/2006/09/12/ssis_3a00_-checking-if-a-row-exists-and-if-it-does_2c00_-has-it-changed.aspx), but in the final step i should write the data in the table, for the rows that have been updated and i don't figured out how to do that. I have been searching and i found an object that could be the answer: OLE DB Command, what do you think guys??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your data is already on sql server use "Execute SQL Task".

If you create data flow use "Derived column" to update values.

Comment: So just add OLE DB Destination  and configure it: choose table and mapping.

Comment: but an OLE DB destination always insert new rows, there is not a option to update in this object, am i wrong???

Comment: No because you have to update it before. It should look like this: OleDb Source->Derived Column->OleDb Destination. Here you can find example: http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/article1233-use-of-derived-column-in-ssis.aspx

Comment: I don't understand why you can't use "EXECUTE SQL Task" if you said that you're executing sp or I missed something...

Comment: oooh that's right devarc, excuse me, i can use "Execute SQL Task" to update data, thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a data flow object, double click on it (to go to the data flow editor) and then add a Source and Destination Objects.

On the source, you type your query (or select table) and on the destination you do the mapping.